# YA fantasy book about two siblings involved with magic. The older sister's name begins with an 'A' and the younger brother's name begins with a 'Z'

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I read it as a child and have spent years trying to find it again. It was a reasonably large book, the first chapter (the introduction of the siblings) talks about the older sister's name beginning with an 'A' and the younger brother's name beginning with a 'Z'. All I remember is that, and that it had something to do with magic.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you can think of?

Comment: This rings a semi-specific bell but I'll have to do some extensive digging to check on it so please give us an idea of *when* you read this story if nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like ***[Spellbound](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2436547.Spellbound)*** (2006) by Anna Dale.

> How far would you go to get rid of an annoying brother? Athene meets the Gloam, who cast a spell on everyone who knew her little brother so that they forget all about him. However, it is Athene who cannot forget her brother and so she sets out into a world of dark magic, underground kingdoms and twisted histories to save him.

The story centres on a girl named Athene and her younger brother, Zach, and a paragraph on the first page of the first chapter notes that they're so dissimilar that even the first letters of their names are at opposite ends of the alphabet.

> No two siblings could have been so dissimilar as Athene and Zach. They were as distinct from each other as chalk is from cheese. Even their names were at opposite ends of the alphabet.

You can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Spellbound/Yt7YVm8t6-MC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: It is spellbound!!!! Thank you so much! I’ve spent years trying to find that book. I read it in a library when I was about 9 back in 2006 and really enjoyed it but was never able to remember the name or find it again! Thank you so so much

Comment: @Sascha Bruce - If this answer is correct, please don't forget to mark it answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. You can tell if you've done it correctly, because the check mark will turn green, and you'll receive +2 [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Sascha Bruce - I just realised that you created a new account to post that thank you comment, which suggests you can no longer access your original account. In order to mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), you'll need to merge the two accounts, so that the site will recognise you as the author of the question. You can merge the two accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).